Is N年 short for N年生?
I am a bit confused about the usage of N年 in this sentence.

1年で入学して1週間のうちに3年まで統制した。

It seems like 1年で is short for 1年生で and 3年まで is short for 3年生まで. The sentence means In a week after entering school as a first year student, he ruled the whole school, even third year students.

It’s not an authoritative source of course, but Wiktionary agrees that 一年 can be a synonym for 一年生 (https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E5%B9%B4), and perhaps the pattern continues from there?

Yes, it is common to call n年生 simply n年 in colloquial speech. Like, When a kid says "3年がいじめる", he is bullied by the third-grader.
Also, n年 can stand for n-th grade as a whole (I mean, 1st-6th in elementary school, and again 1st in secondary school, etc..), rather than the set of individuals, this time even in more formal situations. There's a book for teachers titled 「小学３年の担任になったら」= "When you are assinged to the 3rd grade", and there are news headlines regarding "中学n年の生徒" getting arrested or injured.
I don't think we give conscious distinction between the two.

In a week after entering school as a first year student, he ruled the whole school, even third year students.

That's correct. (And yes, looking at the sentence, I feel it's no wonder one gets confused.)

We do this in English, too: we might say "the third-years" rather than "the third-year students".
